# "App\Entity\User object not found by the @ParamConverter annotation"

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I have a problem with one of my route when I try to access it, I have this error : "App\Entity\CompanyUser object not found by the @ParamConverter annotation"

Many people have the same problem but none of the solutions I could see could solve my problem.

My function edit :

```
private $passwordEncoder;

public function __construct(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
{
    $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
}

/**
 * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="company_user_edit", methods={"GET","POST"}, requirements={"id"="\d+"})
 */
public function edit(Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder, CompanyUser $user): Response
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $reset_password_form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(CompanyResetPasswordType::class, $user);
    $reset_password_form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($reset_password_form->isSubmitted() && $reset_password_form->isValid()) {

        $this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($this->getUser(), $request->get('password'));
        $oldPassword = $request->request->get('reset_password')['oldPassword'];

        // Si l'ancien mot de passe est bon
        if ($passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $oldPassword)) {
            $newEncodedPassword = $passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPlainPassword());
            $user->setPassword($newEncodedPassword);

            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();

            $this->addFlash('notice', 'Succeed to change your password');

            return $this->redirectToRoute('company_show', ['id' => $user->getCompany()->getId()]);

        } else {
            $reset_password_form->addError(new FormError('Old password is not valid'));
        }
    }

    $edit_form = $this->createForm(CompanyUserType::class, $user);
    $edit_form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($edit_form->isSubmitted() && $edit_form->isValid()) {
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('company_show', ['id' => $user->getCompany()->getId()]);
    }

    return $this->render('user/edit.html.twig', [
        'user' => $user,
        'edit_form' => $edit_form->createView(),
        'reset_password_form' => $reset_password_form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the ParamConverter like this

```
/**
 * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="company_user_edit", methods={"GET","POST"}, requirements={"id"="\d+"})
 * @ParamConverter("id", class="CompanyUser", options={"id": "id"})
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was with the wrong router name for the entire controller. I used a generator that did this automatically.
documents:

```
/**
 * @Route("/document")
 */
class DocumentController extends AbstractController


/**
 * @Route("/document/group")
 */
class DocumentGroupController extends AbstractController
```

I changed the name of the router

```
@Route("/document/group")
```

to

```
@Route("/document_group")
```

Comment: dangit ! same thing just happened here. tnx for sharing your solution

Answer (score 0):

The old {id} part of the route has to change to the same name as the parameter you are converting.

I.e. change:

```
 * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="company_user_edit", methods={"GET","POST"}, requirements={"id"="\d+"})
```

To

```
 * @Route("/{user}/edit", name="company_user_edit", methods={"GET","POST"}, requirements={"id"="\d+"})
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Symfony 5.4

I have the route to fetch user profile

###### routes.yaml

```
manage-users:
    path: /Account/{id}/Manage
    controller: App\Controller\RegistrationController::manage
```

When there is a request for a random user id the ***Object not found*** error was thrown. I added User object parameter default value as null and included a null check in the controller method.

###### RegistrationController.php

```
public function manage(User $user = null) <= Default parameter value
{
    try {
        if(null === $user) {
            $this->addFlash("error", "User Not Found");
            return $this->redirectToRoute("home");
        }
     ...
     ...
```

Hope this is helpful, If anyone is checking this issue.